# Printing email headers into a file in python

Tags: python, email

I have a file with each line containing the subject of an e-mail, probably encoded in utf-8 or big-5. I would like to decode these subjects in python and print them to a file. I am using Python's 
email.header.decode_header. The following code, which prints to a file doesn't work:

```
from email.header import decode_header
    f = open("subjects.txt", 'r')
    g = open("transformed_subjects", 'w')
for line in f:

    dh = decode_header(line)
    print >> g, ' '.join(s.decode(enc or 'ascii') for s,enc in dh )
f.close()
g.close()
```

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "read_subjects.py", line 8, in <module>
print >> g, ' '.join(s.decode(enc or 'ascii') for s,enc in dh )
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 68-74: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But when I print to stdout, everything works:

```
from email.header import decode_header
f = open("subjects.txt", 'r')

for line in f:
    dh = decode_header(line)
    print ' '.join(s.decode(enc or 'ascii') for s,enc in dh )
f.close()
```

What is the difference?

Comment: In last part (without `print`) you print to nowhere. You only join elements and do nothing with new string so Python doesn't have to worry about encoding. You can try to encode string before print.

Comment: @furas, thank you for pointing out the error. That was a typo and I fixed it. I'd like to actually save as unicode characters and that gives similar problems.

Comment: Have you try `g.write()` and/or `open(encoding=...)`

Comment: I just tried. The same problem still shows up.

Comment: try `print >> g, ' '.join(s.decode(enc or 'ascii') for s,enc in dh ).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: When you `print` to terminal Python encodes the unicode object to string (=serialization) that suites to your environment.  However a file object has no encoding so Python tries to encode them to ASCII.  However BIG-5 characters do not fit in the ASCII, that's why it raised error.  By explicitly set `encode('utf-8')`  Python can serialize the unicode object.  I didn't know UTF-8 was what you wanted but that's one of the encoding that supports BIG-5 character set. Hence the answer

Comment: So I was right saying `You can try to encode string before print.`. Nice :)

Comment: There's still a problem: after transformation, there's a space between every two characters. So, "Hello" becomes "H e l l o".

Comment: Unless I see the raw email text I can't tell.  Probably the alphabet is multi-byte character.